# Is there a bug in Series.hasNot?

Tags: f#, series, deedle

The help for function `Series.hasNot` in `Deedle` says:

`Returns true when the series does not contains value for the specified key`

The function does not seem to be working this way in the following example:

```
let election =
             [ "Party A", 304
               "Party B", 25 
               "Party C", 570
               "Party Y", 2
               "Party Z", 258 ]
             |> series
let bhnt =
    election
    |> Series.hasNot "Party A"
printfn "%A" <| bhnt
// true
// val bhnt : bool = true
// val it : unit = ()
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Updated my comment with a workaround you can use until this bug is fixed in Deedle.

Comment: The bugfix for this [has been merged into Deedle master](https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/issues/360#event-1720300141), so the next Deedle release should have this fixed. I don't have any information on when that release will be since I'm not part of the Deedle project, but you could check back at https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle every so often to watch for a new release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just looked at the [Deedle source](https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/blob/d4acfa54f4112ac8143db9ba55b138fcff2b8c10/src/Deedle/SeriesModule.fs#L369-369) and saw the following:

```
let has key (series:Series<'K, 'T>) = series.TryGet(key).HasValue
let hasNot key (series:Series<'K, 'T>) = series.TryGet(key).HasValue
```

Yes, you've found a bug. The `hasNot` function should have looked like `not (series.TryGet(key).HasValue)`.

**Workaround:** Until this bug is fixed, you can work around it by replacing all occurrences of `Series.hasNot key` in your code by `Series.has key` and then piping through the `not` function. E.g.,

```
let bhnt =
    election
    |> Series.has "Party A"
    |> not
```

Or, if you think it looks better, you could also write that as:

```
let bhnt =
    election
    |> (not << Series.has "Party A")
```

These two ways of writing it are equivalent; which one you prefer to use will depend on how comfortable you are with functional programming. Some people find the `<<` syntax more natural to read, while others find it completely weird and want to stick to using only `|>`. It all depends on how experienced you are with functional programming; pick whichever of these two feels the most natural to you.

Comment: I've submitted https://github.com/BlueMountainCapital/Deedle/pull/361 to fix this bug.

Comment: Thanks for sending the fix! I need to figure our what is wrong with the CI and get it merged!